# ¿Por qué al insertar un dato de tipo double me genera este mensaje "valor incorrecto para cast"?

Tags: java, poo, ms-access

verán en mi metodo he declarado la variable(Precio) de tipo double y mientras que en mi base de datos  numero decimal.Pero no entiendo porque me genera ese mensaje.

Campos en mi DB [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi capa datos

```
package Datos;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class vexamenes {
    private int Id_examen;
    private String Nombre;
    private  double Precio;
    private int Id_grupoExamen;

    public vexamenes(int Id_examen, String Nombre, double Precio, int Id_grupoExamen) {
        this.Id_examen = Id_examen;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;

        this.Precio = Precio;
        this.Id_grupoExamen = Id_grupoExamen;
    }

    public vexamenes() {
    }

    public int getId_examen() {
        return Id_examen;
    }

    public void setId_examen(int Id_examen) {
        this.Id_examen = Id_examen;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }


    public Double getPrecio() {


        return  Precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(Double Precio) {
        this.Precio = Precio;

    }

    public int getId_grupoExamen() {
        return Id_grupoExamen;
    }

    public void setId_grupoExamen(int Id_grupoExamen) {
        this.Id_grupoExamen = Id_grupoExamen;
    }    
}
```

mi capa lógica

```
package Logica;
import Datos.vexamenes;
import java.sql.Connection; 

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 *
 * @author Mayde2
 */
public class hexamenes {
    private  Conexion access = new Conexion();
    private  Connection cn= access.conectar();
    private String sAccess="";
    public Integer totalregistros;


   public  DefaultTableModel mostrar(String buscar) throws SQLException{
       DefaultTableModel modelo;

       String [] titulos = {"ID", "Exámen", "Precio"};
       String [] registro = new String [3];
       totalregistros=0;
       modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

       sAccess = "select * from  tbl_examenes where Nombre like '%" + buscar + "%'  order by Id_examen desc";

       try{
           Statement st = cn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sAccess);

           while(rs.next()){
               registro [0] = rs.getString("Id_examen");
               registro [1] = rs.getString("Nombre");
               registro [2] = rs.getString("Precio");


//               NumberFormat numeroFormateado =  new DecimalFormat("0.00");
//               Double a = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("Precio"));
//               String b = "$"+numeroFormateado.format(a);
//               registro [2] = b; 
//               
               totalregistros = totalregistros+1;
               modelo.addRow(registro);
           }
           return modelo;
       } catch (Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
           return null;
       }
    }
     public boolean insertar(vexamenes dts){
         sAccess = "insert into tbl_examenes (Nombre, Precio)" +
                "values (?,?)" ;

         ///ahhh
         //programa decian seran facil decian xD
         try {
             PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement (sAccess);
             pst.setString(1, dts.getNombre());

             pst.setDouble(2, dts.getPrecio());

             int n = pst.executeUpdate();
             if (n!=0){
                 return true;
             }
             else{
                 return false;
             }



         } catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
             return false;
         }
     }





     public boolean editar(vexamenes dts){
         sAccess = "update tbl_examenes set  Nombre=?,Precio=?"+
            " where Id_examen=?";
         try {
             PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement (sAccess);
             pst.setString(1, dts.getNombre());

             pst.setDouble(2, dts.getPrecio());
             pst.setInt(3, dts.getId_examen());

             int n = pst.executeUpdate();
             if (n!=0){
                 return true;
             }
             else{
                 return false;
             }

         }          catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
                                  return false;
     }

     }
public boolean eliminar (vexamenes dts){
    sAccess = "delete from tbl_examenes where Id_examen=?";
         try {
             PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement (sAccess);

             pst.setInt(1, dts.getId_examen());

             int n = pst.executeUpdate();
             if (n!=0){
                 return true;
             }
             else{
                 return false;
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
             return false;
         }
}
}
```

En el evento guardar:

```
        dts.setPrecio_venta(Double.parseDouble(txtprecio_venta.getText()));
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Los decimales en tu base de datos utilizan una coma o un punto?

Comment: Como mencionan en otro comentario el double es un numero en coma flotante, por lo que contendrá decimales. Si en tu BBDD es un entero no podrá contener estos últimos y saltara el error

Comment: Hola, si llevan punto

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que me fije en tu base de datos tiene definido number con precision 18 y escala 0, esto significa que podras guardar datos enteros.
Si quieres guardar decimales dentro de la base de datos tienes que ponerle la escala con la cantidad de decimales que quieras guardar (en tu caso 2).

Ademas me fije que el precio dentro del programa lo envias como 0.00, tambien debes verificar como es la conversion de . y , dentro de la base de datos.